# Speech recognition network error on Angular

Tags: angular

Hi I'm making a speech recognition web app on angular 7. I am using webkitSpeechRecognition. But I am getting an network error everytime. It is not taking any input. Whatever I say, it throws error on the console. I don't know why this error is being raised.

Here is my Code

**Service**

**speechrecog.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

interface IWindow extends Window {
  webkitSpeechRecognition: any;
  SpeechRecognition: any;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpeechrecogService {
  speechRecognition: any;
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

  record(): Observable<string> {

    return Observable.create(observer => {
        const { webkitSpeechRecognition }: IWindow = <IWindow>window;
        this.speechRecognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        this.speechRecognition.continuous = true;
        // this.speechRecognition.interimResults = true;
        this.speechRecognition.lang = 'en-us';
        this.speechRecognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

        this.speechRecognition.onresult = speech => {
            let term = '';
            if (speech.results) {
                const result = speech.results[speech.resultIndex];
                const transcript = result[0].transcript;
                if (result.isFinal) {
                    if (result[0].confidence < 0.3) {
                        console.log('Unrecognized result - Please try again');
                    } else {
                        term = _.trim(transcript);
                        console.log('Did you said? -> ' + term + ' , If not then say something else...');
                    }
                }
            }
            this.zone.run(() => {
                observer.next(term);
            });
        };

        this.speechRecognition.onerror = error => {
            observer.error(error);
        };

        this.speechRecognition.onend = () => {
            observer.complete();
        };

        this.speechRecognition.start();
        console.log('Say something - We are listening !!!');
    });
}

DestroySpeechObject() {
    if (this.speechRecognition) {
        this.speechRecognition.stop();
    }
}

}
```

Here is my component :

**speechtotxt.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { SpeechrecogService } from '../speechrecog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-spechtotxt',
  templateUrl: './spechtotxt.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spechtotxt.component.css']
})
export class SpechtotxtComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  showSearchButton: boolean;
  speechData: string;

  constructor(private speechRecognitionService: SpeechrecogService) {
    this.showSearchButton = true;
    this.speechData = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('hello');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.speechRecognitionService.DestroySpeechObject();
  }

  activateSpeechSearchMovie(): void {
    this.showSearchButton = false;

    this.speechRecognitionService.record()
        .subscribe(
        // listener
        (value) => {
            this.speechData = value;
            console.log('jkhkjhkjk', value);
        },
        // errror
        (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            if (err.error === 'no-speech') {
                console.log('--restatring service--');
                this.activateSpeechSearchMovie();
            }
        },
        // completion
        () => {
            this.showSearchButton = true;
            console.log('--complete--');
            this.activateSpeechSearchMovie();
        });
}

}
```

**speechtotxt.component.html**

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="header">
                  <h4 class="title">&nbsp;&nbsp; Web Speech API in Angular2</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label></label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" name="txtSpeechSearchMovieName" id="txtSpeechSearchMovieName" value=""
                                     placeholder="Click below button and then say something!!!" [(ngModel)]="speechData" style="width:500px">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                  </div>
                  <br />
                  <div class="text-center">
                      <button class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd" name="btnActivateSpeechSearchMovie" id="btnActivateSpeechSearchMovie" (click)="activateSpeechSearchMovie()"
                              [disabled]="!showSearchButton">
                          Enable Speech Search
                      </button>
                  </div>
                  <br />
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOdVu.jpg)

This always shows up in console, whenever I'm saying something

SpeechRecognitionError {isTrusted: true, error: "network", message: "", type: "error", target: SpeechRecognition, …}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: SpeechRecognition {grammars: SpeechGrammarList, lang: "en-us", continuous: true, interimResults: false, maxAlternatives: 1, …}
defaultPrevented: false
error: "network"
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
message: ""
path: []
returnValue: true
srcElement: SpeechRecognition {grammars: SpeechGrammarList, lang: "en-us", continuous: true, interimResults: false, maxAlternatives: 1, …}
target: SpeechRecognition {grammars: SpeechGrammarList, lang: "en-us", continuous: true, interimResults: false, maxAlternatives: 1, …}
timeStamp: 6534.664999999222
type: "error"
**proto**: SpeechRecognitionError

I don't understand why this is being raised and how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you inline the error message into your question? The linked imgur screenshot may break or go away, leaving future readers without context.